# Should I include post request in Express for building a public api?

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, express

So, I'm building a public RESTapi for testing so I can have my own set of data to fetch.i'm using Express and MongoDB. And I'm interested if I should add post request, because then the user could update the data in the API. So I'm interested what is the best practice when building such API?

Comment: If you are worried about random users spamming your POST API's, you could try using basic-auth module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth. Alternatively, if you are sceptical of using 3rd party libraries, you may add a secret header and validate based on it

Comment: I decided to go for a secret header and later on add a sort of admin auth so only I can add to the API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to an APi, so it would depend on what you're trying to achieve. As you're learning, I recommend that you start with creating a small project - for me personally, that's the best way to learn. There are also lots of courses out there, I would recommend the Nodejs course by Andrew Mead on Udemy.

So, getting down to it, try and create a simple todo api where the user can add a todo, update and delete it. This would require POST, PATCH and DELETE requests to be sent. (check out postman for sending API calls easily). Finally, a GET request would retrieve all the todos.

I would also recommend looking into userIds, timestamps and JWT tokens to authorize users.

Check out my github (repository named MongoDB), I've done a small tutorial on something similar...

www.github.com/nugoo1

Comment: I understand that, I've already made some basic APIs and used Postman. I was just wondering for this particular API, I wanted to publish it on Heroku, and then use as dummy data to test my frontend apps. Don't know if you understood what I asked, I just was wondering if I should include a POST request, i.e to add data to a collection, in the API, because then some random user could add data, and mess with database.

Comment: Ahhh I see... Well you could run some simple authentication to get this done. For example, make sure the POST request header has a uniqueAuthId sent with the request, and from the API you can make some conditional logic to only save data that has the uniqueAuthId as a header, if not send back a 401 (unauthorized).